# how setting a location by latitude longitude in gmap3

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

good afternoon,
  I am using the plugin gmap3 (http://gmap3.net), and I am not able to set the location where you will center the map and display the marker.

Explanation: I save the value of latitude and longitude in the database. For example "-29.165708760531277, -51.51253212137226".
  and another screen, I want to open showing that location.
  I'm trying to do this:

```
   var localizacao = $("#localizacao").text();

        $("#mapEditar").gmap3({
          marker:{
            latLng: [localizacao],
              draggable:true
            },
          },
          map:{
            options:{
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            }
          }
        });
```

where the variable "localizacao", this value will be the longitude latitude.

But using this way, it is not showing the map.
  Is there a better way to do this?
  What do am I doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to start it looks like you have an extra curly brace in your code

```
var localizacao = $("#localizacao").text();

$("#mapEditar").gmap3({
      marker:{
        latLng: [localizacao],
          draggable:true
        },
      //}, REMOVED
      map:{
        options:{
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        }
      }
    });
```

And for why latLng is not working with `[localizacao]`, it is because latLng takes two separate parameters separated by a comma, like `["-29.165708760531277", "-51.51253212137226"]`.  The variable localizacao contains a string in the form "-29.165708760531277, -51.51253212137226" which results in `["-29.165708760531277, -51.51253212137226"]`, which won't work because there is only one parameter.

```
var lat = $("#localizacao_lat").text();
var lng = $("#localizacao_lng").text();

$("#mapEditar").gmap3({
      marker:{
        latLng: [lat, lng],
          draggable:true
        },
      map:{
        options:{
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        }
      }
    });
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dopernicus/JvKVD/) that might help :)

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, I understand.
  So I did this: localizacao = "-29.165708760531277, -51.51253212137226";
    var arrayPos = localizacao.split(",");                                             and use like this:latLng: [arrayPos[0],arrayPos[1]],